# Mule Message Property after splitting shows all properties values for splitted message in one field

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

We are trying a scenario where we send a list of requests in one payload, split that payload to individual requests based on some xpath, make individual http outbound calls and aggregate them on the back. Entire process works fine but we tried adding invocation property with extracted value from the splitted message payload and it is showing values of all splitted messages always. Here is the mule flow configuration that I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:https="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.5.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/https/current/mule-https.xsd">
    <!-- HTTPS Connection Configuration With CERTS -->
    <https:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS">
        <https:tls-server  path="/Users/rkesara/opt/MULE/truststore/cacerts" storePassword="changeit" />
    </https:connector>

    <!-- List of transformers that might be useful for this flow -->
    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer outputEncoding="UTF-8" name="DOM_to_XML" doc:name="DOM to XML"/>

    <!-- Root flow that can trigger pull and push functionality -->
    <flow name="PushInventoryFlow" doc:name="PushInventoryFlow">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="PushInventoryFlow - Listing requests payload : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <logger message="PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Splitting listing requests..." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <splitter enableCorrelation="ALWAYS" expression="#[xpath('//listings/listing')]" doc:name="ListingRequestSplitter"/>
        <logger message="PullAndPushInventoryFlow - Number of listing requests found after bunlding : #[header:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE] - current request number : #[header:MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <flow-ref name="ListingMessageProcessorFlow" />

        <collection-aggregator />        
        <logger message="Aggregated Payload-&gt; #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
   </flow>

   <flow name="ListingMessageProcessorFlow" doc:name="ListingMessageProcessorFlow">

        <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Remember correlation">
            <add-message-property value="#[header:OUTBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_ID]" key="cid" />
            <add-message-property value="#[header:OUTBOUND:MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE]" key="cgs" />

            <add-message-property value="#[xpath://listing/section]" key="section" />
        </message-properties-transformer>

        <logger message="ListingMessageProcessorFlow - Invoking listingAPI for Section: #[header:INVOCATION:section] with request payload : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="api-dev.srwd10.com" port="443" path="inventory/listings/v1/" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS" transformer-refs="DOM_to_XML" contentType="application/xml" mimeType="application/xml">
            <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
                <add-message-property key="Authorization" value="Bearer blahblahblah" />
                <add-message-property key="TARGET_HOST" value="srwq12" />
                <add-message-property key="Acccept" value="application/xml" />
            </message-properties-transformer>
        </https:outbound-endpoint>
        <logger message="ListingMessageProcessorFlow - Listing API response : #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

        <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
            <add-message-property value="#[header:INVOCATION:cid]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_ID" />
            <add-message-property value="#[header:INVOCATION:cgs]" key="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" />
        </message-properties-transformer>

    </flow>

</mule>
```

Following the request xml:

```
<listings>
   <listing>
      <eventId>4457573</eventId>
      <eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription>
      <pricePerTicket>
         <amount>900</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </pricePerTicket>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section>
      <rows>M</rows>
      <seats>2</seats>
      <splitOption>NONE</splitOption>
   </listing>
   <listing>
      <eventId>4457573</eventId>
      <eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription>
      <pricePerTicket>
         <amount>902</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </pricePerTicket>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section>
      <rows>M</rows>
      <seats>1</seats>
      <splitOption>NONE</splitOption>
   </listing>
   <listing>
      <eventId>4457573</eventId>
      <eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription>
      <pricePerTicket>
         <amount>905</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </pricePerTicket>
      <quantity>2</quantity>
      <section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section>
      <rows>M</rows>
      <seats>4,6</seats>
      <splitOption>NONE</splitOption>
   </listing>
   <listing>
      <eventId>4457573</eventId>
      <eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription>
      <pricePerTicket>
         <amount>906</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </pricePerTicket>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section>
      <rows>M</rows>
      <seats>5</seats>
      <splitOption>NONE</splitOption>
   </listing>
   <listing>
      <eventId>4457573</eventId>
      <eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription>
      <pricePerTicket>
         <amount>907</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </pricePerTicket>
      <quantity>2</quantity>
      <section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section>
      <rows>M</rows>
      <seats>7,9</seats>
      <splitOption>NONE</splitOption>
   </listing>
   <listing>
      <eventId>4457573</eventId>
      <eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription>
      <pricePerTicket>
         <amount>908</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </pricePerTicket>
      <quantity>2</quantity>
      <section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section>
      <rows>M</rows>
      <seats>3,8</seats>
      <splitOption>NONE</splitOption>
   </listing>
   <listing>
      <eventId>4457573</eventId>
      <eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription>
      <pricePerTicket>
         <amount>909</amount>
         <currency>USD</currency>
      </pricePerTicket>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
      <section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section>
      <rows>M</rows>
      <seats>10</seats>
      <splitOption>NONE</splitOption>
   </listing>
</listings>
```

Here is the behavior that we are seeing in logs:

```
INFO  2014-06-25 11:29:07,860 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: PushInventoryFlow - Number of listing requests found after bunlding : 7 - current request number : 1
INFO  2014-06-25 11:29:07,862 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: ListingMessageProcessorFlow - Invoking listingAPI for Section: [CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA] with request payload : <listing><eventId>4457573</eventId><eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription><pricePerTicket><amount>900</amount><currency>USD</currency></pricePerTicket><quantity>1</quantity><section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section><rows>M</rows><seats>2</seats><splitOption>NONE</splitOption></listing>
INFO  2014-06-25 11:29:12,200 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: ListingMessageProcessorFlow - Listing API response Payload: {"listing":{"id":"1082835915","status":"ACTIVE"}}
INFO  2014-06-25 11:29:12,201 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: PushInventoryFlow - Number of listing requests found after bunlding : 7 - current request number : 2
INFO  2014-06-25 11:29:12,202 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: ListingMessageProcessorFlow - Invoking listingAPI for Section: [CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA] with request payload : <listing><eventId>4457573</eventId><eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription><pricePerTicket><amount>902</amount><currency>USD</currency></pricePerTicket><quantity>1</quantity><section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section><rows>M</rows><seats>1</seats><splitOption>NONE</splitOption></listing>
INFO  2014-06-25 11:29:12,695 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: ListingMessageProcessorFlow - Listing API response Payload: {"listing":{"id":"1082835916","status":"ACTIVE"}}
INFO  2014-06-25 11:29:12,695 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: PushInventoryFlow - Number of listing requests found after bunlding : 7 - current request number : 3
INFO  2014-06-25 11:29:12,697 [[telecharge].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.04] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: ListingMessageProcessorFlow - Invoking listingAPI for Section: [CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA] with request payload : <listing><eventId>4457573</eventId><eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription><pricePerTicket><amount>905</amount><currency>USD</currency></pricePerTicket><quantity>2</quantity><section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section><rows>M</rows><seats>4,6</seats><splitOption>NONE</splitOption></listing>
```

Can someone help me pointing out the issue. Just FYI, I am facing a different issue with set-variable on that xpath value. At this point, I wanted to see that for every invocation I maintain values that individual splitted message has but here it gets a value of all splitted messages.

My issue is with this value - just to explain it more

```
ListingMessageProcessorFlow - Invoking listingAPI for Section:

[CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA, CENTER ORCHESTRA]
```

with request payload :

```
<listing><eventId>4457573</eventId><eventDescription>The Book of Mormon Houston</eventDescription><pricePerTicket><amount>900</amount><currency>USD</cur‌​rency></pricePerTicket><quantity>1</quantity><section>CENTER ORCHESTRA</section><rows>M</rows><seats>2</seats><splitOption>NONE</splitOption>‌​</listing>
```

Comment: Thanks David. Moved it to the actual question itself. Can you help with the issue if I am doing something that is causing the issue. I need section field value in that individual splitted message to do further some more logic.

Comment: What version of Mule is this? I see the expression syntax is the old one, not MEL so I assume you use Mule 3.2 or older?

Comment: Not sure if same problem, but i had to specifically pass the payload to the xpath function in order for it to work with the splitter in that way. <splitter expression="#[xpath('//listings/listing', payload)]" />. Otherwise subsequent xpath functions seem to work off the original payload or something. Haven't had chance to look into it.

Comment: @David - I am using 3.5.0 Anypoint Studio but would that matter.

Comment: @Ryan, I think my splitter is working fine. After i split the message, I was trying to use one element of the splitted payload in the flow and when i dump that value - I see values from all splitted messages in one shot with a comma seperated value list.

Comment: You're using old style expressions like `#[xpath://listing/section]` or `#[header:INVOCATION:cid]` so I was wondering if you were on an old version of Mule. And yes version matters: bugs get fixed...

Answer (score 0):

Seems there are a few things you can do to improve this with Anypoint 3.5 or 3.6.

1. Use `xpath('<expression>', payload)` instead of `xpath('<expression>')` as the splitter expression.  The splitter still works fine in terms of splitting the payload into chunks, however, the xpath call in the child flow works against the current chunk of the original payload instead of the whole original payload as it does in your example.  This was mentioned in the comments by @Ryan Carter and is still applicable to Anypoint Studio 3.5.2.
2. Use the current version appropriate setter components which correspond to the item you are setting as @David Dossot mentioned.  Setting a flow variable `<set-variable>` corresponds to what you are currently doing.

   - `<set-property>` for setting a outbound property
   - `<set-variable>` for setting a flow variable
   - `<set-session-variable>` for setting a session variable
3. Use the `<foreach>` scope instead of the splitter-aggregator pattern.  The downside of the splitter-aggregator with XML is that you get a collection of DOM objects that you have to merge into a single object before sending back to the caller.  If you use foreach, then you can modify existing objects in collection since the foreach uses references to the original payload.

   - [How to use XPath with foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725286/how-to-extract-values-from-an-xml-list-in-mule-foreach).
   - If you need to replace the content at the current item in the foreach collection, you can use `rootMessage.payload[counter-1] = payload;` where the right-hand-side payload is the payload of the current for-each iteration that’s only valid for that iteration and the rootMessage.payload is the entire collection.  You can play around to see how well this works with foreach and a DOM payload and XPath collection.