# How to extract values from an xml list in Mule foreach

Tags: xpath, mule, mule-studio

I have a following SOAP response :-

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <retrieveAllDataResponse xmlns="http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1">
         <retrieveAllData>
            <Response>The Data retrieved from the Database</Response>
            <Id>1231</Id>
            <Name>test1</Name>
            <Age>560</Age>
            <Designation>Software Engineer</Designation>
         </retrieveAllData>
         <retrieveAllData>
            <Response>The Data retrieved from the Database</Response>
            <Id>165</Id>
            <Name>test2</Name>
            <Age>561</Age>
            <Designation>Senior Software Engineer</Designation>
         </retrieveAllData>
         <retrieveAllData>
            <Response>The Data retrieved from the Database</Response>
            <Id>134</Id>
            <Name>test3</Name>
            <Age>562</Age>
            <Designation>HR</Designation>
         </retrieveAllData>
</retrieveAllDataResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Now I want to extract the values from the list `<retrieveAllData>` and put into flow variables under **foreach** :-

```
<foreach collection="#[xpath('//xmlns:retrieveDataResponse/xmlns:retrieveAllData')]" doc:name="For Each">
<set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#[xpath('//xmlns:Id/text()').text]" variableName="id"/>
<logger level="INFO" message="#[flowVars['id']]" doc:name="Logger"/>
<set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#[xpath('//xmlns:Name/text()').text]" variableName="name"/>
<logger level="INFO" message="#[flowVars['name']]" doc:name="Logger"/>
<set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#[xpath('//xmlns:Age/text()').text]" variableName="age"/>
<logger level="INFO" message="#[flowVars['age']]" doc:name="Logger"/>
<set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#[xpath('//xmlns:Designation/text()').text]" variableName="designation"/>
```

But I am not getting the values into the variables.. I am getting the following :-

```
 Splitter returned no results. If this is not expected, please check your split expression
```

Please note that I have already set **XML namespace Manager** for the namespace ..

Please let me know is there any better way to get all the values from the list and set it into the flow variables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<flow name="xmlsplitter" doc:name="xmlsplitter">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:/var/lib/data" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>    
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[payload:]" doc:name="Logger" /> 
    <foreach collection="#[xpath('//out:retrieveAllData')]" doc:name="For Each">

        <set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#[xpath('out:Designation/text()').wholeText]" variableName="id"/>
        <logger level="INFO" message="#[flowVars['id']]" doc:name="Logger"/>

    </foreach>      
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a problem with the namespaces, `xmlns` is used to indicate the root namespace of an element and its children, however you are using an xpath using it as prefix, i.e: `//xmlns:retrieveDataResponse/xmlns:retrieveAllData'`, which is wrong. Try defining namespace myNameSpace the URI `http://services.test.com/schema/MainData/V1` and then use it in the xpath fuction: `//myNameSpace:retrieveDataResponse/myNameSpace:retrieveAllData'`.

Also if you are using namespaces you will likely have problems with xpath functions as per [MULE-6508](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6508), try also the wordaround of disabling the inclusions of the mule namespaces.

Finally if this is for an ongoing development, please give it a try to the very-soon-to-be-released Mule 3.6 that includes a much improved support for XML as per [wiki](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/wiki/%5B3.6-M3%5D-Support-for-XPath,-XSLT-and-XQuery-v3.0) and [jira](https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-7030).

Comment: Hi Victor... Thank you for your response ... The issue was not with the namespace .. rather I found it strange as `<set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#[xpath('out:Designation/text()').wholeText]" variableName="id"/>` is working fine where as `<set-variable doc:name="Variable" value="#[xpath('out:Designation/text()').text]" variableName="id"/>` is not working ... May be it's because of this **wholeText** in the xpath .. But I am not sure why

Answer (score 0):

So the final working solution is using the following XPATH and is working for me :- `#[xpath('out:Designation/text()').wholeText]`